# Ungrouping a pandas dataframe after aggregation operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation

I have used the `groupby()` method on my dataframe to find the total number of people at each location. My dataframe's columns are "location" (city names), "name" (names of people in the city), and a "people" column (which just has a "1" for each entry).

```
dataframe.groupby(by=['location'], as_index=False)['people'].agg('sum')
```

To the right of the "sum" column, I need to add a column that lists all of the people's names at each location (ideally in separate rows, but a list would be fine too).

Is there a way to "ungroup" my dataframe again after having found the sum?

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. You simplw want to `groupby(location)`, **but keep columns 'name' and 'sum',** then aggregate so 'sum' counts 1 for each person. Don't do anything to 'name' column, it will persist in the output, which is what you want. (Btw you don't even need to declare column 'people' with those dummy 1's, you can just use 'count'). So simply: `df.groupby('location').agg('people':'count')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two different things:

(1) Create an aggregate DataFrame using `groupby.agg` and calling appropriate methods. The code below lists all names corresponding to a location:

```
out = dataframe.groupby(by=['location'], as_index=False).agg({'people':'sum', 'name':list})
```

(2) Use `groupby.transform` to add a new column to `dataframe` that has the sum of people by location in each row:

```
dataframe['sum'] = dataframe.groupby(by=['location'])['people'].transform('sum')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for 'transform' ?

```
dataframe.groupby(by=['location'], as_index=False)['people'].transform('sum')
```